# How to access component column?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I have a grid to which I add a component column.For each row I set an icon on that column.

So there might be row 1 with icon 'plus' and row two with icon 'print'.
I need to sort the grid according to those icons like clicking on the column and bring all rows with 'print' icons first and those with 'plus' icon later,or vice versa.

I can't find a way to access the rows that have a certain icon programmaticaly, while the column is not even part of the underlying data provider.It's not just icons.Take that away and replace it with a column say that stores Integers.There's no way to get that value by iterating through that grid or dataprovider.

I want to do that for sorting them.Loop over the  rows that have the 'plus' icon to assign value 1 in an adjustent (artificial?) field in the underlying dataset or field/column on grid,while for those with 'print' assign the value of 0.
I want to do that so I can sort the rows by that value.So rows with 0 come first and rows with 1 later on,because I think that's the way of doing it.

I'm sorry if it does sound rather confusing,but in essence I need to find out how you can with Vaadin access a field/column of a row and change that value in the underlying dataset,**or** access the row on the grid and get the column value.

Also what is the difference between **addcomponentcolumn** and **addcolumn**?

Comment: addComponentColumn is just a helper method that calls addColumn with a ComponentRenderer internally. These will produce exactly the same effect: `grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(person -> new Button(person.getName())));` and `grid.addComponentColumn(person -> new Button(person.getName()));`

Answer (score 3):

You are approaching that problem from the wrong direction. Your component renderers are using some data to determine which icon to render. So instead of checking which icon has been rendered, you want to sort the grid based on the data that is used determine the rendered icon. Checking the cell's rendered content would also not work for large grids, as the component only renders the rows that are currently visible in the viewport, while sorting should take into account all the rows.

There is an example in the documentation that demonstrates how to set a sort comparator on a column that uses a custom renderer (second example in the linked section): https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/grid/#sorting.

Example code from the linked example:

```java
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>(Person.class, false);
grid.addColumn(createEmployeeRenderer()).setHeader("Employee")
        .setAutoWidth(true).setFlexGrow(0)
        .setComparator(Person::getLastName); // Specify property to sort by,
                                             // or implement a custom comparator
```